# I'm new to coding and am going through Tech with Tim's chatbot tutorial. I cannot figure out how to solve this error

Tags: python, pycharm, chatbot

```
    import nltk
from nltk.stem.lancaster import LancasterStemmer
stemmer = LancasterStemmer()

import numpy
import tflearn
import tensorflow
import random
import json
import pickle

with open("/Users/Jerrodthompson/Documents/intents.json") as file:
    data = json.load(file)

try:
    with open("data.pickle", "rb") as f:
        words, labels, training, output = pickle.load(f)
except:
    words = []
    labels = []
    docs_x = []
    docs_y = []

    for intent in data["intents"]:
        for pattern in intent["patterns"]:
            wrds = nltk.word_tokenize(pattern)
            words.extend(wrds)
            docs_x.append(wrds)
            docs_y.append(intent["tag"])

        if intent["tag"] not in labels:
            labels.append(intent["tag"])


    words = [stemmer.stem(w.lower()) for w in words if w not in "?"]
    words = sorted(list(set(words)))

    labels = sorted(labels)

    training = []
    output = []

    out_empty = [0 for _ in range(len(labels))]

    for x, doc in enumerate(docs_x):
        bag = []

        wrds = [stemmer.stem(w.lower()) for w in words if w != "?"]

        for w in words:
            if w in wrds:
                bag.append(1)
            else:
                bag.append(0)

        output_row = out_empty[:]
        output_row[labels.index(docs_y[x])] = 1

        training.append(bag)
        output.append(output_row)

    training = numpy.array(training)
    output = numpy.array(output)

    with open("data.pickle", "wb") as f:
        pickle.dump((words, labels, training, output), f)

tensorflow.reset_default_graph()

net = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, len(training[0])])
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 8)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 8)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, len(output[0]), activation="softmax")
net = tflearn.regression(net)

model = tflearn.DNN(net)

try:
    model.load("model.tflearn")
except:
    model.fit(training, output, n_epoch=1000, batch_size=8, show_metric=True)
    model.save("model.tflearn")

def bag_of_words(s, words):
    bag = [0 for _ in range(len(words))]

    s_words = nltk.word_tokenize(s)
    s_words = [stemmer.stem(word.lower()) for word in s_words]

    for se in s_words:
        for i, w in enumerate(words):
            if w == se:
                bag[i] = 1

    return numpy.array(bag)

def chat():
    print("Start talking with the bot (type quit to stop!")
    while True:
        inp = input("You: ")
        if inp.lower() == "quit":
            break

        results = model.predict([bag_of_words(inp, words)])
        results_index = numpy.argmax(results)
        tag = labels[results_index]

        for tg in data["intents"]:
            if tg['tag'] == tag:
               responses = tg['responses']
        print(random.choice(responses))

chat()
```

Error Code:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:From /Users/Jerrodthompson/PycharmProjects/justanotherchatbotattempt/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tflearn/collections.py:13: The name tf.GraphKeys is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.GraphKeys instead.
```

WARNING:tensorflow:From /Users/Jerrodthompson/PycharmProjects/justanotherchatbotattempt/venv/main.py:70: The name tf.reset_default_graph is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.reset_default_graph instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From /Users/Jerrodthompson/PycharmProjects/justanotherchatbotattempt/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tflearn/layers/core.py:66: The name tf.placeholder is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.placeholder instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From /Users/Jerrodthompson/PycharmProjects/justanotherchatbotattempt/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tflearn/layers/core.py:69: The name tf.add_to_collection is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.add_to_collection instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From /Users/Jerrodthompson/PycharmProjects/justanotherchatbotattempt/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tflearn/initializations.py:173: calling TruncatedNormal.**init** (from tensorflow.python.ops.init_ops) with dtype is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Call initializer instance with the dtype argument instead of passing it to the constructor
WARNING:tensorflow:From /Users/Jerrodthompson/PycharmProjects/justanotherchatbotattempt/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tflearn/variables.py:44: The name tf.get_variable is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.get_variable instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From /Users/Jerrodthompson/PycharmProjects/justanotherchatbotattempt/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tflearn/optimizers.py:238: The name tf.train.AdamOptimizer is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.train.AdamOptimizer instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From /Users/Jerrodthompson/PycharmProjects/justanotherchatbotattempt/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tflearn/layers/estimator.py:96: The name tf.get_collection is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.get_collection instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From /Users/Jerrodthompson/PycharmProjects/justanotherchatbotattempt/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tflearn/objectives.py:114: calling reduce_sum_v1 (from tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops) with keep_dims is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
keep_dims is deprecated, use keepdims instead
WARNING:tensorflow:From /Users/Jerrodthompson/PycharmProjects/justanotherchatbotattempt/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tflearn/objectives.py:118: The name tf.log is deprecated. Please use tf.math.log instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From /Users/Jerrodthompson/PycharmProjects/justanotherchatbotattempt/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tflearn/layers/estimator.py:141: The name tf.trainable_variables is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.trainable_variables instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From /Users/Jerrodthompson/PycharmProjects/justanotherchatbotattempt/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tflearn/helpers/trainer.py:457: The name tf.get_default_graph is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From /Users/Jerrodthompson/PycharmProjects/justanotherchatbotattempt/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tflearn/config.py:130: The name tf.assign is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.assign instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From /Users/Jerrodthompson/PycharmProjects/justanotherchatbotattempt/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tflearn/helpers/trainer.py:95: The name tf.Session is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.Session instead.

2020-01-11 13:40:33.068166: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
2020-01-11 13:40:33.085284: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x7fbfbc0cbc80 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-01-11 13:40:33.085301: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Jerrodthompson/PycharmProjects/justanotherchatbotattempt/venv/main.py", line 78, in 
    model = tflearn.DNN(net)
  File "/Users/Jerrodthompson/PycharmProjects/justanotherchatbotattempt/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tflearn/models/dnn.py", line 57, in **init**
    session=session)
  File "/Users/Jerrodthompson/PycharmProjects/justanotherchatbotattempt/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tflearn/helpers/trainer.py", line 111, in **init**
    clip_gradients)
  File "/Users/Jerrodthompson/PycharmProjects/justanotherchatbotattempt/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tflearn/helpers/trainer.py", line 561, in initialize_training_ops
    ema_num_updates=self.training_steps)
  File "/Users/Jerrodthompson/PycharmProjects/justanotherchatbotattempt/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tflearn/summaries.py", line 243, in add_loss_summaries
    summaries_collection_key)
  File "/Users/Jerrodthompson/PycharmProjects/justanotherchatbotattempt/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tflearn/summaries.py", line 46, in get_summary
    summ = tf.scalar_summary(tag, value)
  File "/Users/Jerrodthompson/PycharmProjects/justanotherchatbotattempt/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/util/module_wrapper.py", line 193, in **getattr**
    attr = getattr(self._tfmw_wrapped_module, name)
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'scalar_summary'

Answer (score 0):

A warning is not an error. In this case it is just giving you information that advises you to use a different API method, as the one you are currently using is 'deprecated' (it will not be available in future releases but works for now).

Try replacing

```
tf.GraphKeys
```

with

```
tf.compat.v1.GraphKeys
```

as it suggests and the error should disappear.

Answer (score 0):

There is no error in your code but libraries you use they are old for the first part you can use

```
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter('ignore', FutureWarning)
```

at top of code, and then you will only get

```
WARNING:tensorflow
```

for that you either have to edit code in

```
~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/LibrabrName
```

Or if just don't want to see a warning and don't care about them use

```
import os
os.system("clear")
```

at end of imports